# Give error 404 on purpose on an existing url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I received an abuse complaint from my hosting company because a spammer is sending phishing emails linking to a gif in my domain.

Unfortunately the image is linked with a thumbnails php page and I want to filter only that particular url with mod_rewrite

the url is similar to this

http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/Broadcast/thumb.php?src=http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/image.gif&w=594&h=300&zc=1&q=100

how can I give 403 or 404 to this particular url?

If I move the image file to another path the page is an error page (thumb.php) but with a 400 header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting this rule in `wp-content/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-content/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /themes/Broadcast/thumb\.php\?src=http://www\.mysite\.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/image\.gif&w=594&h=300&zc=1&q=100
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be [replacing the file with a different one with the same name](http://ascii.textfiles.com/archives/1011).